# C# Obfuscate source code which is getting installed using the Visual studio setup wizard

Tags: c#

How could I protect my .NET applications source code (classes) which are getting installed using the **visual studio setup wizard**?

I've been using the https://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/ application to obfuscate my exe and dll files. Now I want to serve the application using the visual studio setup wizard but it's delivering the class files and everything else non-obfuscated.

What could I do?

I appreciate any kind help.

Comment: Use signed assemblies. Obfuscation is a just a tarpit, it doesn't protect anything.

Comment: What are you trying to protect in the first place?

Comment: Why is your installer installing classes?

Comment: Configure a post build event to call the command line obfuscation tool, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this. It does not cover the installer creation, but it should work anyway.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1040107/Configuring-Visual-Studio-for-Obfuscation